# Finding a formula for a 3D shape and colouring it

Tags: graphics

I created a wall with line command

```
Manipulate[Graphics3D[{
     (*Right front*)
     Line[{{-(h/100)*15 - (h/10)*2, 0, -(0.4 + (h/100)*15)},
          {(h/2) + (h/10)*2 + (h/100)*15 + 0.4, 0, -(0.4 + (h/100)*15)}}],
     Line[{{(h/2) + (h/10)*2 + (h/100)*15 + 0.4, 0, -(0.4 + (h/100)*15)},  
          {(h/2) + (h/10)*2 + (h/100)*15 + 0.4, 0, 0}}],
     Line[{{(h/2) + (h/10)*2 + (h/100)*15 + 0.4, 0, 0}, {0.4, 0, 0}}],
     Line[{{0.4, 0, 0}, {0.4, 0, h}}],
     Line[{{0.4, 0, h}, {0, 0, h}}],
     Line[{{0, 0, h}, {-(h/100)*15, 0, 0}}],
     Line[{{-(h/100)*15, 0, 0}, {-(h/100)*15 - (h/10)*2, 0, 0}}],
     Line[{{-(h/100)*15 - (h/10)*2, 0, 0},
          {-(h/100)*15 - (h/10)*2, 0, -(0.4 + (h/100)*15)}}],
     (*Back front*)
     Line[{{(h/2) + (h/10)*2 + (h/100)*15 + 0.4, 0, -(0.4 + (h/100)*15)},
          {(h/2) + (h/10)*2 + (h/100)*15 + 0.4, h, -(0.4 + (h/100)*15)}}],
     Line[{{(h/2) + (h/10)*2 + (h/100)*15 + 0.4, h, -(0.4 + (h/100)*15)},  
          {(h/2) + (h/10)*2 + (h/100)*15 + 0.4, h, 0}}],
     Line[{{(h/2) + (h/10)*2 + (h/100)*15 + 0.4, h, 0},
          {(h/2) + (h/10)*2 + (h/100)*15 + 0.4, 0, 0}}],
     Line[{{(h/2) + (h/10)*2 + (h/100)*15 + 0.4, h, 0}, {0.4, h, 0}}],
     Line[{{0.4, h, 0}, {0.4, 0, 0}}],
     Line[{{0.4, h, 0}, {0.4, h, h}}],
     Line[{{0.4, h, h}, {0.4, 0, h}}],
     (*Left front*)
     Line[{{(h/2) + (h/10)*2 + (h/100)*15 + 0.4, h, -(0.4 + (h/100)*15)},
          {-(h/100)*15 - (h/10)*2, h, -(0.4 + (h/100)*15)}}],
     Line[{{-(h/100)*15 - (h/10)*2, h, -(0.4 + (h/100)*15)},
          {-(h/100)*15 - (h/10)*2, h, 0}}],
     Line[{{-(h/100)*15 - (h/10)*2, h, 0}, {-(h/100)*15, h, 0}}],
     Line[{{-(h/100)*15, h, 0}, {0, h, h}}],
     Line[{{0, h, h}, {0.4, h, h}}],
     (*Frontface*)
     Line[{{-(h/100)*15 - (h/10)*2, h, -(0.4 + (h/100)*15)},
          {-(h/100)*15 - (h/10)*2, 0, -(0.4 + (h/100)*15)}}],
     Line[{{-(h/100)*15 - (h/10)*2, h, 0}, {-(h/100)*15 - (h/10)*2, 0, 0}}],
     Line[{{-(h/100)*15, h, 0}, {-(h/100)*15, 0, 0}}],
     Line[{{0, h, h}, {0, 0, h}}]},
     Boxed -> True, PlotRange -> {{-12, 12}, {0, 12}, {-3, 12}}, 
     Axes -> True], 
     Style["Altezza del muro in base alla necessità:", 12, Bold],
     {h, 2, 10}, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

How can I re-create that wall with function(s)? (It will be better if I can use `ParametricPlot3D` or some other function)

And can I fill that shape with colors? (I want that the wall seems a solid figure).

Comment: Instead of parametric equations I would use `Polygon` to create non-transparent faces.  What is your goal?  Why do you think `ParametricPlot3D` is better?

Comment: I have to create a 3D shape (whatever real object that can change in time, for example a volcano shooting stones from his mouth or other things...)   and I was thinking about a wall that changes his dimension... but I should make that object with functions,  If you have a better Idea I'm glad to listen it :), anyway I suggested ParametricPlot3D because of the possibility to create 3D-Shapes with functions with that command...

Comment: I did say what would be better: use `Polygon`s.

Comment: I don't know how to do xD

Comment: Did you already look up `Polygon` in the documentation?  You already have the lines, now using the same coordinates include the polygons as faces.

Comment: Thanks both of you :), I solved using Polygon :D

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
p[t_,t1_] := Transpose@{{-7 t, 8 + 17 t, 8 + 17 t, 8, 8, 0, -3 t, -7 t, -7 t}, 
           Array[20 t1 &, 9], {-8-3 t,-8-3 t, 0, 0, 20 t, 20 t, 0,  0, -8-3 t}}/20
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{FaceForm[Transparent], Polygon@p[h,0], Polygon@p[h,h], 
             Line /@ Transpose[{p[h,0], p[h,h]}]}, Boxed -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-12, 12}, {0, 12}, {-3, 12}}, Axes -> True], 
  {h, 2, 10}, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

All polygons, solid faces:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{FaceForm[White], Polygon@p[h,0], Polygon@p[h,h], 
   Polygon /@ Partition[Flatten[Transpose[{Partition[p[h,0], 2, 1], 
                                 Reverse /@ Partition[p[h,h], 2, 1]}], 2], 4]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-12, 12}, {0, 12}, {-3, 12}}, Axes -> True], 
{h, 2,   10}, ControlPlacement -> Left]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: This way the wall is still transparent, I want it to seem a solid block...

Comment: @Marco There you've it